# Will current flow through both loops of the 2nd circuit?

Tags: kirchhoffs-laws

[image]

I have following two circuits. In 1st circuit(figure 1.a), I can join ground terminal of R2 with node D,so that current can flow as in loop A-B-D-E-A and loop B-C-D-B.

But I am confused with figure 1.b. In this circuit, current can flow in loop as M-N-S-T-M but I don't understand can there be current flow in the loop O-P-Q-R-O or not?

Comment: no , it's floating at V(N)

Comment: no, the voltages at O,P,Q and R are all the same (= N = +V). Without any voltage difference there is no current.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All the current from V *must* flow through R1, so effectively no current will flow through the second loop.